# Calculation of a time interval a time list until the next time mark is more than x minutes away

Tags: excel, vba, formula

This is the data sample we have where A is a timestamp, B is the starting time, C is the ending time.

```
~~~A~~~~~~~~~~B~~~~~~~~~~C~~~~~~~~~        
14:44:09  14:44:09    
14:45:03
14:45:43
14:46:32
14:47:41
14:48:22
20:03:35  20:03:35    
20:07:03
20:13:41
20:14:12
20:15:06
20:16:12
21:13:41  21:13:41    
21:14:52
21:35:18
```

At C1, I want to have the timestamp 14:48:22. That time is specifically chosen by a rule that states "if the time difference between two timestamps is greater than 10 minutes, the smaller timestamp gets written at the beginning of that series" which would be C2 in this case. To illustrate my point, see below.

```
~~~A~~~~~~~~~~B~~~~~~~~~~C~~~~~~~~~        
14:44:09  14:44:09    14:48:22
14:45:03
14:45:43
14:46:32
14:47:41
14:48:22
20:03:35  20:03:35    20:16:12
20:07:03
20:13:41
20:14:12
20:15:06
20:16:12
21:13:41  21:13:41    21:35:18
21:14:52
21:35:18
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column B is relatively easy:

**B1** is simply `=A1`
**B2** is `=IF(A2>A1+TIME(,10,),A2,"")` which checks the time next to it against the time previously, and if it's over 10 minutes, put the time in the cell, else put an empty string

The C column is a little more interesting

First, we need to find the next time shown in the B column, which, using the answer from [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/349154-find-first-non-blank-cell-row.html), gives us:

```
INDEX(B2:B15,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((B2:B15<>""),0),0))
```

now we have the value, we use MATCH to find it in column A, subtract 1 from the location to get the previous time, and report that.

```
=INDEX(A2:A15,MATCH(INDEX(B2:B15,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((B2:B15<>""),0),0)),A2:A15,0)-1,0)
```

We wrap it in an IF statement to make sure it's blank when the corresponding cell in B is blank, and we end up with a very horrible looking formula like this in C1:

```
=IF(B1="","",INDEX(A2:A15,MATCH(INDEX(B2:B15,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((B2:B15<>""),0),0)),A2:A15,0)-1,0))
```

The only drawback to this equation is that the last result gives an `#N/A`, but you can either just fix that manually, or wrap the formula with an **IFERROR** statement, giving the behemoth equation of:

```
=IFERROR(IF(B1="","",INDEX(A2:A15,MATCH(INDEX(B2:B15,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((B2:B15<>""),0),0)),A2:A15,0)-1,0)),MAX(A:A))
```

Copy **B2** down, and **C1** down to get the result you requested. adjust the B15 and A15 in the formula to match your full data set.